# How to implement a 3-try authorization for passwords?

Tags: python

```
elif loginChoice=="Doctor" or loginChoice=="doctor":
    inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code) "))
    while True:
        if inputPass != adminPass:
            for tries in range (0,2):
                print("Wrong password! Only "+str(2-tries)+" tries left.")
                inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code) "))
                if inputPass==adminPass:
                    break;
                if tries==2:
                    break;
            break;
        else:
            print("Permission granted...")
            print(" ")
```

So I'm creating a sort of self-diagnosis program for self-improvement and I created a doctor's login method so the user can access data in arrays. Therefore, I've added a password to this login with a 3-try login attempt. However I've realized that if I get the password wrong once, it executes the if loop which includes an "Only wrong attempts" loop and even if I write the correct password the 2nd time, it won't exit out of this loop and put me into the "else:" function. Any way to combat this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it so complicated and messy just create one variable which can keep track of attempts that a user makes if user attempts is 4 loop will automatically stops Try this:

```
if loginChoice=="Doctor" or loginChoice=="doctor":
    #inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code) "))
    noOfattempts = 0
    while noOfattempts != 3:
        inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code): "))
        if inputPass != adminPass:
            # for tries in range (0,2):
            #     print("Wrong password! Only "+str(2-tries)+" tries left.")
            #     inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code) "))
            #     if inputPass==adminPass:
            #         break;
            #     if tries==2:
            #         break;
            # break;
            noOfattempts+=1
        else:
            print("Permission granted...")
            print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making it more like this:

```
adminPass = 'asdf' # just put this in for testing purposes
tries = 0
while True:
    inputPass=str(input("Input doctor's password:(see line 1 of code) "))
    if inputPass == adminPass:
        passwordCorrect = True
    else:
        passwordCorrect = False
        print("Wrong password! Only "+str(2-tries)+" tries left.")
        tries += 1

    if tries > 1:
        print("Wrong password! Permission denied.")
        break

    if passwordCorrect:
        print("Permission granted...")
        print(" ")
        break
```